# Shifting points via edit ribbon in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, editing, move

I have a point layer (graveyard) and I need to shift the points, but it is not letting me "select" the points to edit them, in the edit ribbon.

I select a rectangle and it won't highlight the point to move further into the edit ribbon process.
The layer is editable -- but I used a Trimble handheld to collect the points -- I have been able to add to the attribute table -but not move any points that were collected to match up to the clearest satellite image of the site.

Is it because I used the handheld, as it will not even let me select the points to be able to edit them?

Comment: Is the source of your graveyards layer a file geodatabase feature class, a shapefile or something else?

Comment: Is the layer selectable? When you say "select a rectangle" are you using the general selection tools from the Ribbon? Sometimes edit wants you to choose a tool from the Editing popup. You may need to select from there.

Comment: PolyGeo - its a point layer - feature class but I created it using a Trimble handheld from the Local College /as part of project- so I am not as familiar with them -it worked very much like the collection app

Comment: danak - I will try this /using from editing popup / and report back /select a rectangle,is from the selection drop down , and I was trying to use that to encompass the point to be shifted ? but it never "highlights" it into the selection pane -so then can never move forward with editing-as it never is highlighted

Comment: In the Edit ribbon do you already have the Move tool selected? Some of the other tools (like Explode) require a multipolygon to work, and if you have that tool selected they will automatically unselect any features that don't meet the requirements.